# Was it ever revealed where the Bionts came from?

Tags: video-games, aquanox, archimedean-dynasty

In Archimedean Dynasty (original title "Schleichfahrt") the Bionts that are encountered by the underwater humans seem to have established facilities over ground. There are some very vague hints regarding the Biont's history, but I was wondering where they came from. Have they evolved from biological life forms, similar to the Borg?

Answer (score 1):

they were human, like us, but instead of working on a solution like NOX to handle the high pressures of deepsea life and breathing gases , they developed an cyborg solution.

as time went on they embraced technical solutions to anwser issues they struck, and lost their connection to thieir human past.

think of them as an very early borg from star trek.

Comment: Hi and welcome to scifi.stackexchange.com. Thank you for trying to provide an answer to this question, but your post appears to be based solely on conjecture. We prefer answers that manage to back up their claims with some sort of evidence (perhaps some part of the story that strongly indicates you claims to be the truth or a statement from one of the game developers / story-authors). For instance, you theory appears a bit hard to believe since they explicitly state that the Biont scout ships are completely *unmanned* (in the very first game).

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time, but I don't really remember any story explanation of their origin or history (at least nothing specific in the games; although I think I've never finished the third game).

Thinking about this, you shouldn't forget about the fact that this game is essentially "from another time". Back then most games had very simple plot lines consisting of not more than "bad guys appear, have to shoot them!". From what I remember the only details that are revealed are:

- The Survion is located short off the cost of former Sidney.
- Some of the structures might extend up to the surface (but as far as I know they're never sure).
- I think there's never been any mention of the ships having any organic origin. They're called Bionts due to the assumption that they're "living" ships (i.e. self-aware; maybe sentient).

To add on the Borg question:

- They use a black/green color scheme due to it appearing a lot more creepy. There aren't that many color options to use: blue would appear more harmless and red wouldn't make them that special (as many other ships used red colors; plus not using red adds more contrast to things like lava and explosions (despite the fact that there's no lava outside FMVs).
- They use similar shapes to Borg (lots of corners and cuts, no rounded surfaces) as this makes them look a lot more technology oriented (less about style). Essentially they've got this in common.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get how this answers the question? You state some interesting facts but none of which relate directly to their origin. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What I tried to say: It's never been explained or mentioned (where they're from) and I can't remember any hints that they were once somehow human or whatever. Edited the first sentence to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry, but giving "it's never been mentioned, because I don't remember" with partial knowledge doesn't really help, right?